# Scala design pattern - sealed trait with two generics, children method having same type object in arguments list

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types

sorry if the title is not very explicative, but I don't know how to explain it. I'm a scala newbie and I'm struggling in finding a solution to my problem. Here's the snippet:

```
sealed trait Base[T, M] {
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def initialize(v: T): this.type = {
    value = Some(v)
    this
  }
  def combine[K <: M](other: K): M

}

class Child1 extends Base[String, Child1] {

  override def combine[K <: Child1](other: K) = {
    val c = new Child1()
    c.initialize(value.get + " - " + other.value.get)
    c
  }

}

class Child2 extends Base[Long, Child2] {
  override def combine[K <: Child2](other: K) = {
    val c = new Child2()
    c.initialize(value.get + other.value.get)
    c
  }
}


object Main extends App {
  val c1a = new Child1()
  c1a.initialize("a")
  val c1b = new Child1()
  c1b.initialize("b")

  val c21 = new Child2()
  c21.initialize(1)
  val c22 = new Child2()
  c22.initialize(2)

  val m1 = Map("child1" -> c1a, "child2" -> c21)
  val m2 = Map("child1" -> c1b, "child2" -> c22)

  m1("child1").combine(m2("child1"))
}
```

What I want to achieve is that each subclass of `Base` can be combined only with objects of the same type.

The compiler complains when calling the `combine` method due to a mismatch in the type of the argument. Is this a correct approach? Or the structure of the classes for my purpose is to be rewritten?

**EDIT**

This should be ok as well:

```
sealed trait Base[T, M] {
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def initialize(v: T): this.type = {
    value = Some(v)
    this
  }
  def combine(other: M): M

}

class Child1 extends Base[String, Child1] {

  override def combine(other: Child1) = {
    val c = new Child1()
    c.initialize(value.get + " - " + other.value.get)
    c
  }

}

class Child2 extends Base[Long, Child2] {
  override def combine(other: Child2) = {
    val c = new Child2()
    c.initialize(value.get + other.value.get)
    c
  }
}
```

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

The solution I found so far:

```
val combined = (m1("child1"), m2("child1")) match {
  case (a: Child1, b: Child1) => a.combine(b)
  case _ => throw new Error("Error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to achieve is that each subclass of Base can be combined
>   only with objects of the same type.

Instead of using pattern match on `(m1("child1"), m2("child1"))` you can directly use type check on `combine` method on each child class. In addition, your code seem more imperative style, such as using `var`, I have refractored your code in more functional way.

```
sealed trait Base[T] {
  val value: Option[T] = None
  def combine[Other](other: Base[Other]): Base[T]
}

case class Child1(override val value: Option[String]) extends Base[String] {
  override def combine[Other](other: Base[Other]) = {
    other match {
      case v: Child1 => this.copy(v.value)
      case _ => throw new Error("Error")
    }
  }
}

case class Child2(override val value: Option[String]) extends Base[String] {
  override def combine[Other](other: Base[Other]) = {
    other match {
      case v: Child2 => this.copy(v.value)
      case _ => throw new Error("Error")
    }
  }
}
val child1 = Child1(Some("child1"))
val child2 = Child2(Some("child2"))
child1.combine(child2)  //Will fail
val anotherChild1 = Child1(Some("Another child1"))
child1.combine(anotherChild1) //Will succeed.
```